# Method accessible only to classes in the Static Library

Tags: ios, objective-c, static-libraries, visibility

I'm building a Static Library for iOS and I'd like to have some methods accessible to all the classes in the library, but not outside the library. Let's make an example:

This is a class called A with two methods available outside the library:

```
@interface A : NSObject

-(void)methoAvailableOutside1;
-(void)methoAvailableOutside2;

//This method has to be visible only to classes within the library
-(void)methodInternalToTheLibrary;

@end
```

The class called B is still internal to the library. It can call all methods belonging to A (also the method that should be "internal"):

```
#import "A.h"

@interface B : NSObject

@property A* aObject;

@end
```

This is the implementation of B:

```
#import "B.h"

@implementation B

-(instancetype)init{
    self = [super init];

    if(self){
        _aObject = [[A alloc]init];
        [_aObject methoAvailableOutside1];
        [_aObject methoAvailableOutside2];

        //here I can call the "internal" method
        [_aObject methodInternalToTheLibrary];
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

Now let's write an EXTERNAL class (external to the library, clearly):

```
#import "MyCustomLibrary.h"

@interface ExternalClass : NSObject

@property A* aObject;

@end
```

This is the implementation of the external class:

```
#import "ExternalClass.h"

@implementation ExternalClass

- (instancetype)init
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        _aObject = [[A alloc]init];
        [_aObject methoAvailableOutside1];
        [_aObject methoAvailableOutside2];

        //!!!Here THIS SHOULD BE...
        [_aObject methodInternalToTheLibrary];
        //...FORBIDDEN!!!
    }

    return self;
}

@end
```

How can I achieve this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to have an additional header file with the additional method defined in that header. Anonymous categories.

```
publicHeader.h
@interface A : NSObject
-(void)methoAvailableOutside1;
-(void)methoAvailableOutside2;
@end
```

And then a mother .h file only used inside your library code.

```
privateHeader.h
@interface A()
//This method has to be visible only to classes within the library
-(void)methodInternalToTheLibrary;
@end
```

Could that work? It won't guarantee that other code can't call the method but the intention would be clear.